# Construct two classes that has attributes and can use methods of each other

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'd like to know is it possible that two classes has attributes and can use methods of each other. For example, there're a class **STUDENT** and a class **COURSE**, a STUDENT have a list of joined courses and a COURSE have list of participants(students). I tried this:

in **STUDENT.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// #include "COURSE.h"

class COURSE;

class STUDENT {
    string name;
    std::vector<COURSE*> listCourses;
public:
    STUDENT(){};

    addCourse(COURSE* &course){
        listCourses.push_back(course);
        course.addStudent(this);
    }
    
    string getName(){
       return this->name;
    }
    
    void showCourses(){
       for(COURSE* course : listCourses)
          std::cout << course->getName() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

in **COURSE.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// #include "STUDENT.h"

class STUDENT;

class COURSE {
    string name;
    std::vector<STUDENT*> listStudents;
public:
    COURSE(){}

    addStudent(STUDENT* &student){
        listStudents.push_back(student);
        student.addCourse(this);
    }
      
    string getName(){
       return this->name;
    }
    
    void showStudent(){
       for(STUDENT* student : listCourses)
          std::cout << student->getName() << std::endl;
    }

};
```

If I include two classes each other, it said errors. If I just include one, just one class worked, other class has problem.

Can anyone help me to fix it and I wonder that is it necessary to use some design patterns or data structures to solve this.
Thank you

Comment: Separate class member declaration from definition.

Comment: `STUDENT::addCourse` will never work this way; also the use of a reference to a pointer instead of simply a reference (or only a pointer) is unnecessary, since you never write to the parameter or take its address. In your case you'd also need this order of occurances in the header (or split into header and implementation: `class COURSE; class STUDENT{ ... void addCourse(COURSE&course); ... }; #include "COURSE.h" inline void STUDENT::addCourse(COURSE& course) { student.addCourse(&course); course.addStudent(*this); }`

Comment: Also the convention in in C++ is to use all-caps only for macros; you'd usually use `Course` and `Student` (or `course` and `student`, if you want to be consistent with the standard library) as type names.

Comment: To expand a bit on @SamVarshavchik's excellent advice: you define the classes in the headers. But that should only include declarations of (at least most) member functions. Then have a course.cpp and student.cpp that each include both headers, and define the member functions for their respective classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you are attempting is possible, but not in the *way* you are attempting it.  You need to separate your method declarations and definitions.

Also, you have a flaw in your `add...` methods that will lead to endless recursion as soon as a `Student` is added to a `Course` or vice versa.  You need to detect when the two are already linked together so that you can avoid the loop.

Try something more like this:

Student.h

```
#ifndef StudentH
#define StudentH

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Course;

class Student {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Course*> listCourses;
public:
    Student() = default;
    ~Student();

    std::string getName() const;

    void addCourse(Course* course);
    void removeCourse(Course* course);
    void showCourses() const;
};

#endif
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

Student::~Student() {
    for(Course* course : listCourses) {
        course->removeStudent(this);
    }
}

std::string Student::getName() const {
    return name;
}

void Student::addCourse(Course* course) {
    if (std::find(listCourses.begin(), listCourses.end(), course) == listCourses.end()) {
        listCourses.push_back(course);
        course->addStudent(this);
    }
}
    
void Student::removeCourse(Course* course) {
    auto iter = std::find(listCourses.begin(), listCourses.end(), course);
    if (iter != listCourses.end()) {
        listCourses.erase(iter);
        course->removeStudent(this);
    }
}
    
void Student::showCourses() const {
    for(Course* course : listCourses) {
        std::cout << course->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Course.h

```
#ifndef CourseH
#define CourseH

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Student;

class Course {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Student*> listStudents;
public:
    Course() = default;
    ~Course();

    std::string getName() const;

    void addStudent(Student* student);
    void removeStudent(Student* student);
    void showStudents() const;
};

#endif
```

Course.cpp

```
#include "Course.h"
#include "Student.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

Course::~Course() {
    for(Student* student : listStudents) {
        student->removeCourse(this);
    }
}

std::string Course::getName() const {
    return name;
}

void Course::addStudent(Student* student) {
    if (std::find(listStudents.begin(), listStudents.end(), student) == listStudents.end()) {
        listStudents.push_back(student);
        student->addCourse(this);
    }
}
      
void Course::removeStudent(Student* student) {
    auto iter = std::find(listStudents.begin(), listStudents.end(), student);
    if (iter != listStudents.end()) {
        listStudents.erase(iter);
        student->removeCourse(this);
    }
}
    
void Course::showStudents() const {
    for(Student* student : listStudents) {
        std::cout << student->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```